# How to access storage without dependency injection on every dialog in botframework V4

Tags: c#, botframework

Hello i am trying to migrate my code from the Bot Framework v4 design last January to the new design now. In the previous code i can just call this code:

```
var userstate = await (stepContext.Context.TurnState["BasicAccessors"] as BasicAccessors).BasicUserStateAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context);
```

on every dialog to access the storage but not i can't do it and i need to to dependency injection everytime. How to implement this code on this new design? Thank you.

```
    namespace BasicBot
    {
    public class BasicAccessors
    {
        public BasicAccessors(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState)
        {
            ConversationState = conversationState ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(conversationState));
            UserState = userState ?? throw new ArgumentException(nameof(userState));
        }

        public static string DialogStateAccessorName { get; } = $"{nameof(BasicAccessors)}.DialogState";

        public static string BasicUserStateAccessorName { get; } = $"{nameof(BasicAccessors)}.BasicUserState";

        public IStatePropertyAccessor<BasicUserState> BasicUserStateAccessor { get; internal set; }

        public IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> DialogStateAccessor { get; internal set; }

        public ConversationState ConversationState { get; }

        public UserState UserState { get; }
    }
}
```

bot code:

```
 public class DialogBot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Dialog
{
    protected readonly Dialog Dialog;
    protected readonly BotState ConversationState;
    protected readonly BotState UserState;
    protected readonly ILogger Logger;

    public DialogBot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, ILogger<DialogBot<T>> logger)
    {
        ConversationState = conversationState;
        UserState = userState;
        Dialog = dialog;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

        // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
        var userStateAccessors = UserState.CreateProperty<BookingDetails>(nameof(BookingDetails));
        await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation("Running dialog with Message Activity.");

        // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
        await Dialog.Run(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>("DialogState"), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

startup:

```
  public class Startup
{
    public Startup()
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // Create the credential provider to be used with the Bot Framework Adapter.
        services.AddSingleton<ICredentialProvider, ConfigurationCredentialProvider>();

        // Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled.
        services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

        // Create the storage we'll be using for User and Conversation state. (Memory is great for testing purposes.)
        services.AddSingleton<IStorage, MemoryStorage>();

        // Create the User state. (Used in this bot's Dialog implementation.)
        services.AddSingleton<UserState>();

        // Create the Conversation state. (Used by the Dialog system itself.)
        services.AddSingleton<ConversationState>();

        services.AddSingleton<BasicAccessors>();

        // The Dialog that will be run by the bot.
        services.AddSingleton<MainDialog>();

        // Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
        services.AddTransient<IBot, DialogBot<MainDialog>>();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have the solution for this yet, but you don't need to do dependency injection on every dialog access. You just setup the dependency in the startup, set up your accessors in your bot, then you can just access the properties as needed. Take a look at the [article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and the [sample here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/45.state-management). This does a decent job of showing how it should all be set up.